# Declaration Expected xmlDoc.Load()

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to read an RSS feed and am trying to use the following code to do so.  The line `xmlDoc.Load(rssStream)` returns the following error when I try to run the page through Visual Studio:

> Declaration expected

I am led to believe that something is wrong with my VB.NET syntax on that line, but I can't figure out what the issue could be.

```
<script runat="server"> 
   Dim rq AS WebRequest=WebRequest.Create("feedurl")
   Dim response AS WebResponse=rq.GetResponse()
   Dim rssStream As Stream =response.GetResponseStream()
   Dim xmlDoc As XMLDocument=new XMLDocument()

   xmlDoc.Load(rssStream)

   Dim xmlNodeList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/channel/item/title | /channel/item/link")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the `XElement.Load("feedurl")` and then LINQ to XML rather than XML DOM to manipulate it. Alternatively, you can use the `SyndicationFeed` methods in WCF to get more strongly typed access to RSS. I discuss both solutions at [my blog](http://linqinaction.net/blogs/jwooley/archive/2007/10/12/adding-rss-posts-to-thinqlinq-using-system-servicemodel-syndication-syndicationfeed.aspx).

Comment: It seems like this would make a better comment than an answer, since it doesn't actually answer the question.  I agree that, if he cannot find a solution, these are excellent alternatives, but it doesn't answer the question of why it's failing with `XmlDocument`.  Are you suggesting that there is some reason why using `XmlDocument` in this particular situation cannot work?  If so, please explain.